# Problem with installing AdventureWorks on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, adventureworks

I have encountered a problem with importing a backup of `AdventureWorksDW2017`. I tried to install the backup of it, following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15, however most of the options listed in there, like Tasks, Restore Database, etc. seem to be missing in my installation.

Currently, I am using SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server Management Studio 18. I tried reinstalling it, hoping that the reason could be a corrupted installation, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You can't restore a `SQL Server 2017` backup to a `SQL Server 2016`. Use  `AdventureWorks2016.bak` instead

Comment: It seems you are connected to Analysys Services rather than the SQL Server database engine. AdventureWorksDW2017 is a relational database.

Comment: I connected to the database engine and that was exactly what I was looking for, issue solved.